# Default export not explicitly defined

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I refer to this type definition file: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/nodemailer/index.d.ts, which has a total of nine exports: 3 each of `type`, `interface`, and `function`.

There is no default export defined in this file. However, I am able to do the following:

```
import NM from "nodemailer";
```

and then `NM` can access the three functions exported: `createTestAccount`, `createTransport`, and `getTestMessageUrl`. For the other exports in that file, I have to import explicitly, for example:

```
import { SendMailOptions, Transporter } from "nodemailer";
```

Where is the default export defined for this type definition?

In the same project, I created my own test module with an export but not declaring it as a default. The compiler balked if I imported using the default syntax.

My compiler option for `module` is ES2015, if it is of any relevance.

Answer (score 0):

You must have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in your `tsconfig` file. This *allows default imports from modules with no default export.*

If there is no default export typescript imports the module as if you had written `import * as NM from 'nodemailer'`

Comment: But out of say, 10, exports in the file, who decides which ones are in the default?

Comment: @OldGeezer Only "value" exports (not "type")

Comment: I added a test module with an exported function, and `import * as test from "./test"` works but `import test from "./test"` says "has no default export".

Comment: `--esModuleInterop` is also necessary  unless you are using an additional tool, such as Babel, webpack, or SystemJS and to wish to delegate the provision of the synthetic default to them